# Turn off struts validation per input box based on checkbox value

Tags: struts, validation

I have a struts application that has a form to edit user details. I am using struts validator to validate the user input.

I have a checkbox that, when clicked, makes 'Password' and 'Confirm Password' input boxes appear.

If the checkbox box is UNchecked, I do not want the app to validate the invisible input boxes. If I check the checkbox, I then want the validator to kick it.

I have put an c:if around the  to only display if the checkbox is checked.

My problem is that the Password/Confirm password validation kicks in, but is invisible.

My question is, is there a way to only validate an input box based on a checkbox value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but i believe you can use validWhen" validation, this validation is for such use-cases for more details refer to the official doc

[validator](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.5/faqs/validator.html)

Comment: I need more help... 

I have removed the checkbox from the screen. The scenario now is that the password and confirm password boxes are visible. If you don't want to update your password, you leave the boxes empty. If you do want to change, you fill in the details.

Comment: I have my valication.xml with the password property 'password' as follows:

            <field property="password"
                    depends="mask,validwhen">
                <arg0 key="createUser.password"/>
                <var>
              <var-name>mask</var-name>
              <var-value>^[<![CDATA[^<>\&\r\n\\\"\'\|]]>]+$</var-value>
          </var>
          <var>
                    <var-name>test</var-name>
                    <var-value>(*this* == null)</var-value>
                </var>             
            </field>

Comment: If you add a password, it must adhere to the mask.
If you do not add a password, validation will pass.

I need to have an 'either/or' check.. As it stands, validation will pass if the password box is empty. If you add a password that adhere's to the rules, validation rightly fails because password != null.


Anyone any ideas?